# Integrate Google Calendar Events in iOS app calendar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate the Google Calendar API in my iOS app written in Swift.
But the library is updated and I am unable to find the new code that implements Google Calendar APIs.

Please help me to get all the meeting details of Google Calendar in iOS app.